# How to set up a database in a class

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

New C# dev here, and I'm working on my first desktop application.  I have a class set up that will do all of my SQL Server CE database work.  Inside of my class, I have a few static strings set up that I am using to create the database, and I will use the same connection string to connect to the database.

```
    private static string DBFileName = "engine.msbdb";
    private static string DBPassword = "msb";
    private static string DBConnectionString = string.Format("DataSource=\"{0}\"; Password='{1}'", DBFileName, DBPassword);
```

Now comes my question.  In each of my methods that I have taking actions on my database, do I need to make a new connection in each of my methods?  I can't necessarily create the connection in the constructor, because the database hasn't been created yet.  How would I go about using the same connection in each of my methods so I don't have to rewrite all of the code each time I need to connect to the database?  Do I simply write a private method that connects to the database and returns the database connection object?  Just at a loss  and can't figure out where to go from here.  Sorry in advance if this question is a little confusing as I am still learning how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in your class for the SqlCeConnection object. Call the Open() and Close() from each method in your class that needs it.

```
private SqlCeConnection conn { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application is small scale desktop app, nothing wrong in creating SqlConnection as a private variable within each method. Try using it within a using statement for better disposing

```
using (SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(DBConnectionString)){
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Emp",connection)) 
    {

    }
}
```

Once you get a hang of C# and DotNet in general, try to read on **Repository** and **UnitOfWork** patterns. These patterns will help you to better isolate your data access logic

Hope this helps